# custom cursor in actionscript 3 event doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3

the custom cursor is a sprite.
using it to click another sprite no longer triggers the MouseEvent.Click event.
it looks like my custom cursor is being clicked on the sprite i want to click

Is there something i need to enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
customCursor.mouseEnabled = false; //as well as
customCursor.mouseChildren = false;
```

should solve the problem