# AS3 - how to get the mouse cursor to click on a button?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my application i have a mouse cursor which is attached to the mouse. However it will not let me click on buttons within my application which is a big problem for me as buttons are essential in what i need to do.

I am new to AS so any help would be much appreciated!

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, draw_cursor);
stage.addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_LEAVE, hide_cursor);

Mouse.hide();

function draw_cursor(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    my_cursor_mc.visible = true;
    my_cursor_mc.x = event.stageX;
    my_cursor_mc.y = event.stageY;
}


function hide_cursor(event:Event):void
{
    my_cursor_mc.visible=false;
}
```

i tried using this (below) but was very glichy and had to press button for cursor to go away THEN i was able to click on the button (not really ideal):

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hide_cursor);
```

Comment: Support for proper custom native mouse cursors was adding in Flash Player 10.2. You can learn about it here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/native-mouse-cursors.html

Comment: Very excellent link, thanks for sharing. I would recommend using native mouse cursors as Adam suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [custom cursor in actionscript 3 event doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528709/custom-cursor-in-actionscript-3-event-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your cursor might be stealing the mouse events for your buttons. In your top level code (or constructor) try adding:

```
// Disable mouse events for cursor    
my_cursor_mc.mouseEnabled = false;
```

If you mouse event has any child objects also add:

```
// Disable mouse events for any children of the cursor
my_cursor_mc.mouseChildren = false;
```